# Unable to locate ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino after sudo apt-get install in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

should i downgrade ubuntu version, why its unable to locate pakage?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242089/hi-while-i-was-installing-rosserial-library-for-arduino-in-ubuntu-16.04-using-command-%22sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino%22-but-its-coming-unable-to-locate-package,how-should-i-resolve-it/) by [rahul](https://answers.ros.org/users/27797/rahul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino" or "sudo apt-get install ros-jade-rosserial-arduino".(This might be helpful cuz Ubuntu 16.04 supports kinetic officially but you can also build the packages separately which is not recommended).
(Download the source from git hub: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial and copy it in your local catkin_ws and run catkin_make. Not a recommended solution but for a workaround.)

I have tried "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosserial-arduino" in Ubuntu 14.04. It is working fine.

you can also change the rosdistro to ros-jade i guess.

---

Originally posted by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) with karma: 80 on 2016-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0